# Creating a default All-Day Calendar Event

Tags: macos, calendar, sonoma

Is it possible to create a default all-day Calendar event?  For instance, something that will have the same Name as well as the same multiple Alert times - so I don't have to renter the same alert times each time I create a new event?  I am using a new M3 Macbook on Sonoma and am new to Mac's.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you edit this to show what Apple product or service you are using? Most of them are scriptable, but let’s help everyone understand if you’re using a Mac or a mobile device or a web page or some other program that’s not Apple design

Comment: I added more info - I did the "Edit question" and enter.  It still shows the question as closed.  Do I need to do anything else to get it posted?

Comment: The moment your edit is complete it goes to a review queue for all the users with reopen permissions to vote. Thank you!